# CSV read issue between Mac and Win - missing \n char

Tags: php, file, csv, file-io

I have a basic csv file reading, but it can't read the csv saved on a Mac platform.

I understood that the issue is from `Different operating system families have different line-ending conventions`, but I cannot fix it.

I've found a suggestion - opening the file in binary mode, but didn't work.

The code is pretty basic:

`file opening`:

```
$this->fileHandler = fopen($this->filename, 'rb');
```

`read line`:

```
$columns = fgetcsv(
    $this->fileHandler,
    $this->length,
    $this->delimiter,
    $this->enclosure
);
```

I've opened both files with Notepad++ and it seems that the Mac file lacks the `\n` characters at the end of rows, but the `\r` is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`auto_detect_line_endings`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) option to `true` before using `fgetcsv()`:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
// rest of your code
```

Comment: That's a great answer. It saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to Mac, but I know that when moving a text file from Windows to some Linux flavors, I can run the `dos2unix filename` command on the file and it'll fix up the formatting for me. Maybe Mac has a similar functionality?

**EDIT:** Maybe this can help: http://schmeits.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/dos2unix-alternative-those-darn-m-characters/

Comment: even if this would be a solution, I don't want to premanipulate the file or change it in any way... thanks --- i could just insert all the `\n` manually next to the `\r` char but seems very inefficient

Comment: You're saying you don't want to "premanipulate" the file but then you're willing to manually add the new line characters?

Comment: I may have been unclear, I could replace, but I don't want to... seems a lot expensive useless code.

Comment: It's one command, not expensive useless code... but Alex Shesterov posted a better solution, so that might be worth taking a look at.